# Cannot read property 'type' of undefined - redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to dispatch an action, but it returns "type" of `undefined`. I suspect Redux Thunk is not working properly.

Before I was dispatching the same action from the parent component and it was working.

Entry point

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import configureStore from '../ConfigureStore'
import '../App.css';
import App from './theapp/theAppContainer';

const store = configureStore()

class Root extends Component {
 render() {
  return (
   <Provider store={store}>
                <App />
            </Provider>
  )
 }
}

export default Root;
```

Store

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger'
import allReducers from './reducers/index'

const loggerMiddleware = createLogger()

export default function configureStore() {
 return createStore(
  allReducers,
  applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, loggerMiddleware)
 )
}
```

The app - routing. Before I was dispatching the action at this level and it was working.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Cards from '../templates/cards/CardsContainer'
import EditApp from '../pages/editApp/EditApp'
import NewApp from '../pages/NewApp'
import AppReport from '../pages/AppReport'
import { Route, Switch, HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

export default class TheApp extends Component {

 constructor(props) {
  super(props)
 }

 render() {

  const appId = window.location.href.split('id=')[1];

  return (
   <HashRouter>
    <Switch>
     <Route exact path="/" component={Cards} />
     <Route path="/app" component={EditApp} />
     <Route exact path="/new" component={NewApp} />
     <Route path="/report" component={AppReport} />
    </Switch>
   </HashRouter>
  )
 }
}
```

The container where I dispatch the action

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Cards from './Cards'
import {
 fetchAppsData
  } from '../../../actions'

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        apps: state.apps
    }
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return dispatch(fetchAppsData)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(Cards)
```

Action

```js
import fetch from 'cross-fetch'
import * as helpers from '../Helpers';
export const REQUEST_ITEMS = 'REQUEST_ITEMS'
export const RECEIVE_ITEMS = 'RECEIVE_ITEMS'

export function fetchAppsData() {
 return (dispatch) => {
  return dispatch(fetchItems())
 }
}

function fetchItems() {
 return dispatch => {
  dispatch(requestItems())
  return fetch(helpers.appData)
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then(json => dispatch(receiveItems(json)))
 }
}

function requestItems() {
 return {
  type: REQUEST_ITEMS
 }
}

function receiveItems(json) {
 return {
  type: RECEIVE_ITEMS,
  items: json,
  receivedAt: Date.now()
 }
}
```

The reducer

```js
import {
    REQUEST_ITEMS,
    RECEIVE_ITEMS
  } from '../actions/apps-actions'
  
export default function apps(
 state = {
  isFetching: false,
  items: []
 },
 action
) {
 switch (action.type) {
  case REQUEST_ITEMS:
   return Object.assign({}, state, {
    isFetching: true
   })
  case RECEIVE_ITEMS:
   return Object.assign({}, state, {
    isFetching: false,
    items: action.items
   })
  default:
   return state
 }
}
```

Comment: And where do you get the error?

Comment: When i dispatch the action in the container: 

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return dispatch(fetchAppsData)
}

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
(anonymous function)
C:/POC Dashboard/poc_dashboard/node_modules/redux-logger/dist/redux-logger.js:354

Comment: `return dispatch(fetchAppsData())`

Comment: return dispatch(fetchAppsData())  thowns another error: 
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Comment: shouldn't `mapDispatchToProps` return an object with action names as keys and dispatch(...) as values ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe calling

```
dispatch(fetchAppsData)
```

isn't correct, `fetchAppsData` is a thunk creator, not a thunk directly.  Instead you would want to do

```
dispatch(fetchAppsData())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return dispatch(fetchAppsData)
}
```

Into this:

```
   function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
        return {
            fetchAppsData: () => dispatch(fetchAppsData())
        }
    }
```

Also the function should be called “mapDispatchToProps”  but that is not important for your problem.